# ¿Cómo detectar cuando un trozo de código HTML se ha cargado y una vez cargado ejecutar una función?

Tags: javascript

Cómo podría detectar que se haya cargado un trozo de código *HTML*.

Estoy trabajando con *PHP* y *Codeigniter 3*, el cual funciona con mvc, mi controlador carga unos datos de base de datos y luego carga una vista, esta vista recorre los datos del controlador que los pinta en *HTML*,
en está vista me gustaría poder ejecutar una función cuando se haya cargado una tabla. Como esta tabla está dentro del *foreach* que recorre los datos del controlador, me gustaría poder ejecutar una petición *Ajax* para otros datos.

Ejemplo de código:

**controlador.php**:

```
 public function blogs()
   {
      $datosBlogs['listaBlogs'] = $this->mimodel->getBlogs();
      $this->load->view('blogs', $datosBlogs);
   }
```

**blogs.php** es un *HTML* pero solo dejo cuando recorro los datos:

```
 <?php foreach ($listaBlogs as $blogs ) { ?>
<label>nombre</label><input readonly type="text"  id="nombre" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $blogs ['nombre'] ?>"><br>
<label>Dirección</label><input readonly type="text" class=" input-sm" id="direccion" name="direccion" value="<?php echo $blogs ['direccion'] ?>"><br>
Comentarios del usuario
<table>
 <thead>
<th>Fecha</th>
<th>Comentario</th>
</thead>
 <tbody onload="cargarComentarios(<?php echo $blogs['IdBlog'] ?>)">
</tbody>
</table>

<?php } ?>


<script>

function cargarComentarios(idBlog) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>inicio/getComentariosIdBlogs",
            data: {
                idBlog: idBlog
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
                $.each(res, function(index, value) {
                    renderizarDatos(value);
                });
            }
        });
    }

function renderizarDatos(datos) {
        camposTD = [datos.Comentario, datos.fecha, datos.Usuario, ]
        let campoTR = crear("tr");

        for (let valor of $camposTD) {
            let campoTD = crear("td");
            console.log(valor);
            campoTD.textContent = valor;
            campoTR.appendChild(campoTD);
        }
         $("tbody").append(campoTR)
    }
</script>
```

Me gustaría poder ejecutar `cargarComentarios` por cada iteración de la listablog, pero no se ejecuta.

Tampoco sé si es la mejor forma de hacer esto, es decir que los comentarios están en los blogs yo obtengo todos los blogs, y luego están los comentarios, que tiene el id del blog es decir que comparten una clave. Y me gustaría poder recorrer todos los comentarios del blog pasándole el id del blog.

> tabla blog (usuario,**id_blog**,direccion);
> tabla comentario (usuario,id_comentario, **id_blog**,fecha,comentario )

Pensé que llamando a la función load se ejecutaría `cargarComentarios`, pero no lo hace.

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar a poder recorrer los comentarios que hay en un blog, o detectar que el tabla se haya cargado y ejecute la función `cargarComentarios`.

Comment: puedes usar `async function y await` o `callbacks`

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas una llamada **AJAX** para hacer lo que pretendes. Por lo que veo lo único que hace esa llamada es pedir los comentarios que tiene un determinado blog, pero esos comentarios ya se los puedes pasar a la Vista desde el Controlador en el momento de cargarla.

Así, la variable `$datosBlogs` que le pasas a la vista podrían tener un aspecto similar a este:

```
Array (
  [0] => stdClass Object (
    [nombre] => Blog 1 
    [autor] => Pepito 
    [comentarios] => Array ([0] => comentario1 [1] => comentario2 [2] => comentario3 ) ) 
  [1] => stdClass Object (
    [nombre] => Blog 2 
    [autor] => Fulanito 
    [comentarios] => Array ([0] => comentario1 [1] => comentario2 [2] => comentario3 ) ) 
)
```

Como ves, sería solamente añadir a los datos que te devuelve la función `getBlogs()` los comentarios de cada uno de los blogs. A la Vista le pasas los datos en formato **JSON** y ya desde **JS** recorres ese **JSON** pintando la tabla de la manera que gustes.

Soy partidario de no hacer llamadas innecesarias al servidor. Todo lo que puedas enviarle a la vista son viajes que te ahorras a pedir los datos. Hay veces que no se puede evitar pero esta no es una de ellas.

Comment: Anda cierto, mejor cargarlos ya desde base de datos. Gracias por tu respuesta y el tiempo.

Comment: Aunque no se me ocurre muy bien la consulta a ejecutar para que me guarde los comentarios y no me repita registros. lo que se me ocurrió fue guardar en una variable esta consulta select * from blog left join comentario on blog.id_blog = comentario.id_blog; y cuando recorro los blogs  en la tabla con un if si el id_blog del blog == id_blog de los comentarios que me recorra los comentarios y me pinte la tabla. No se si será lo  mejor pero me funciono

Comment: Lo malo de esa manera es que vas a recorrer tooodos los comentarios por cada uno de los blogs que tengas, independientemente de si estos pertenecen o no a dicho blog (los recorres todos pero luego pintas solamente los que sean de ese blog). Yo lo que haría sería guardar en un array asociativo los comentarios, donde la clave sea el id_blog y el valor otro array con cada uno de los comentarios. De esa manera, al recorrer el `foreach` de los blogs, puedes usar el id para acceder al array de comentarios, específicamente al del id_blog que corresponda. No sé si me he explicado bien :)

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices ,pero la verdad que no sé hacer lo que me planteas. 
Estoy haciendo algo así en el controlador  
  `public function blogs(){
$datosBlogs['listaBlogs'] = $this->mimodel->getBlogs(); 
$datosComentario= $this->mimodel->comentariosPorBlog(); 
$datosBlogs['listaBlogs'][] = $datosComentario['id_blog']; $datosBlogs['listaBlogs'][] = array('fecha' => $datosComentario['fecha'],'comentario' => $datosComentario['comentario'],'usuario' => $datosComentario['usuario'])
   }`
   **Dices algo así como esto?**